# GoCD POST requests return "The resource you requested was not found!"

Tags: api, go-cd

I have GoCD instance and want to automate regular actions like scheduling pipelines and checking pipelines statuses using GoCD API.

When I do GET request it works:

```
curl 'https://gocd.demo.kagarlickij.com/go/api/pipelines/frankenstein/status' \
 -u 'kagarlickij:Pa$$w0rd' | jq
```

[image]

..but when I do POST request it returns "The resource you requested was not found!":

```
curl 'https://gocd.demo.kagarlickij.com/go/api/pipelines/frankenstein/pause' \
-u 'kagarlickij:Pa$$w0rd' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v1+json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X POST -d '{"pause_cause": "Investigating build failures"}'  | jq
```

[image]

..another POST example:

```
curl 'https://gocd.demo.kagarlickij.com/go/api/pipelines/frankenstein/schedule' \
-u 'kagarlickij:P@$$w0rd' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v1+json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X POST -d @gocd.json  | jq
```

json content:

```
{
    "environment_variables": {},
    "materials": {},
    "update_materials_before_scheduling": false
}
```

[image]

Any ideas how pipelines could be started using API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple - that API actions require GoCD v18.2.0 but I had v18.0.0

After upgrade API calls work as expected

Comment: Hm, that's weird: Pipeline status, pause and schedule are very old, where added in 14.x.x version. Documentation for [old](https://api.gocd.org/17.5.0/#pause-a-pipeline) REST API version shows that there were added in v14.3.0.

Comment: Oh, they introduced *new* pause/unpause REST API: https://github.com/gocd/gocd/issues/4076
With **exactly** same url
 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Some GoCD API calls [require](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd/blob/master/yagocd/resources/pipeline.py#L217-L234) `'Confirm': 'true'` header. 
In you case, you can try running curl like this:

`curl 'https://gocd.demo.kagarlickij.com/go/api/pipelines/frankenstein/pause' \
-u 'kagarlickij:Pa$$w0rd' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.go.cd.v1+json' \ 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ 
-H 'Confirm: true' \
-X POST -d '{"pause_cause": "Investigating build failures"}'  | jq`

I can recommend my lib [yagocd](https://github.com/grundic/yagocd) for GoCD, which takes cares about version incompatibilities and makes working with GoCD API much easier.